# LSTM model has poor prediction results

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

#Forecast future runoff based on meteorological data and historical runoff

```
Streamflow=pd.read_csv('###.csv', delimiter=',')
x = Streamflow.drop('Q',axis=1)   
Y = Streamflow['Q']               
X = np.array(x)                   
y = np.array(Y)
            
test_size = int(len(X) * 0.15)
valid_size = int(len(X) * 0.15)
train_size= len(X) - (valid_size+test_size)
y_train, y_valid, y_test = y[0:train_size], y[train_size:train_size+valid_size], y[-test_size:]
X_train, X_valid, X_test = X[0:train_size], X[train_size:train_size+valid_size], X[train_size+valid_size:]

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))  
X_valid = np.reshape(X_valid, (X_valid.shape[0], 1, X_valid.shape[1]))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))
input=X_train[1:]
input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]
print (y_train.shape, y_valid.shape, y_test.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(150, input_shape=X_train.shape[1:], activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))                                     

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=e_LR) 
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='MeanAbsoluteError')  
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=e_epoch, batch_size=e_batch_size, verbose=0, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), shuffle=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxPh7.png)
This is model loss and the result. The results of the training period and the verification period are acceptable, but the results of the testing period are too poor. How should I modify the model?
(The data is not normalized because the normalized prediction is a straight line. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my reputation is not enough for me to comment directly. You can try the following three solutions: 1. Reduce the learning rate as much as possible 2. Reduce the model complexity, such as reducing the hidden size of LSTM. 3. Increase the number of training rounds.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the results got worse when I turned the learning rate down (especially during the testing and validation periods), and interestingly the results got better when I increased the number of neurons (200 to 2000)

Comment: Sorry, my answer is based on my previous experience with running LSTM with pytorch. The situation at the time was: the loss on the training set was small, but in the end the model predicted a straight line on the test set.